# How can I make a complex T-SQL update query?

Tags: t-sql

I have a database table:

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3
------------------
  1  |   2  |  -
  2  |   3  |  -
  3  |   4  |  -
  4  |   5  |  -
```

Columns 1 and 2 have data but 3 is null.

What I want to achieve is to set `Col3` to the `Col1` value of the previous row (technically the previous row in which the `Col1` value equals the `Col2` value), to get this:

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3
------------------
  1  |   2  |  -
  2  |   3  |  1
  3  |   4  |  2
  4  |   5  |  3
```

I am struggling over the update query in order to achieve this. I have been trying things like:

```
UPDATE Table
SET [cur].Col3 = [prev].Col1
FROM Table [cur], Table [prev]
WHERE [cur].Col1 = [prev].Col2
```

But this doesn't seem to be working for me. SQL Server accepts the syntax in a stored procedure, but when it executes it generates an error:

> Table is ambiguous

What am I doing wrong?

---

#### Note:

The data in each column is already guaranteed to be unique and each combination of `Col1` and `Col2` is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
declare @yourTable table (col1 int, col2 int, col3 int)
INSERT INTO @YourTable values (1,2,NULL)
INSERT INTO @YourTable values (2,3,NULL)
INSERT INTO @YourTable values (3,4,NULL)
INSERT INTO @YourTable values (4,5,NULL)

UPDATE cur
   SET cur.Col3 = prev.Col1
   FROM @YourTable           cur
       INNER JOIN @YourTable prev ON cur.col1=prev.col2

select * from @YourTable
```

output:

```
(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(3 row(s) affected)
col1        col2        col3
----------- ----------- -----------
1           2           NULL
2           3           1
3           4           2
4           5           3

(4 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE [cur] -- <<====== change here
SET [cur].Col3 = [prev].Col1
FROM Table [cur], Table [prev]
WHERE [cur].Col1 = [prev].Col2
```

Comment: in his sample code the table name is [table], and it has the [cur] and [prev] alias values on it

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE [cur] 
SET [cur].Col3 = [prev].Col1
FROM Table [cur]
JOIN Table [prev] on [cur].Col1 = [prev].Col2
```

Please try to start using the join syntax instead of that old style syntax. You will have fewer problems, it will be easier to maintain and no accidental cross-joins. ANd left joins will work correctly as they do not right now with the *= syntax. Plus you will be up-to-date with the 1992 standard.

Answer (score 0):

Change the first line to

```
UPDATE [cur]
```